# how i can make this condition dynamic like instead of 2 put a keyword so it change dynamically

Tags: reactjs

***slider.jsx***

As you can see my code is working fine but in if else there is manually set up like `slideIndex` if it is less than 2 so i want to make it dynamically change so i don't need to write number if have more data object in my data.js

```
const Slider = () => {
        const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0)
        const handleClick=(direction)=>{
            if(direction === "left"){
                setSlideIndex(slideIndex > 0 ? slideIndex-1:2)
            } else {
                setSlideIndex(slideIndex < 2 ? slideIndex+1: 0)
            }
        };
```

***data.js*** this is my data.js file

here in my data.js there is only 3 object but if i add more objects i have set manually in slider.jsx like if i have 5 object so i have to change manually 2 to 4 how i can do this manually

```
export const sliderItems = [
    {
      id: 1,
      img: "https://i.ibb.co/DG69bQ4/2.png",
      title: "SUMMER SALE",
      desc: "DON'T COMPROMISE ON STYLE! GET FLAT 30% OFF FOR NEW ARRIVALS.",
      bg: "f5fafd",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      img: "https://i.ibb.co/DG69bQ4/2.png",
      title: "AUTUMN COLLECTION",
      desc: "DON'T COMPROMISE ON STYLE! GET FLAT 30% OFF FOR NEW ARRIVALS.",
      bg: "fcf1ed",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      img: "https://i.ibb.co/cXFnLLV/3.png",
      title: "LOUNGEWEAR LOVE",
      desc: "DON'T COMPROMISE ON STYLE! GET FLAT 30% OFF FOR NEW ARRIVALS.",
      bg: "fbf0f4",
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this one-**

```js
const Slider = () => {
        const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0)
        const handleClick=(direction)=>{
            if(direction === "left"){
                setSlideIndex(slideIndex==0 ? sliderItems.length-1:slideIndex-1)
            } else {
                setSlideIndex(slideIndex=== sliderItems.length-1 ? 0: slideIndex+1)
            }
        };
```

Comment: You are always welcome @MOHDDANISH & you can also accept my answer so, it will be helpful as well as for other developers.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2 is that last index of your data that means it is just equal to `sliderItems.length - 1`
Wherever in the code you need to check for the last index just write `sliderItems.length - 1`.

This code will be modified as :

```
const Slider = () => {
    const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0)
    const handleClick=(direction)=>{
        if(direction === "left"){
            setSlideIndex(slideIndex > 0 ? slideIndex-1:sliderItems.length)
        } else {
            setSlideIndex(slideIndex < sliderItems.length ? slideIndex+1: 0)
        }
    };
```